# Delete file (not remove) from listview

Tags: vb.net, file, listview

The following removes a listview item, but I want to delete it

How can I do this?

```
 For i As Integer = ListView1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ListView1.Items(i).Selected Then ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
    Next
```

I am using vb.net

Comment: What is the difference between delete and remove?

Comment: I suppose OP want to remove element from the list and delete the file on the disk?

Comment: Delete is to remove the file and remove is to remove a refrence to it from the listview delete is to get rid of and bin as is recycle bin gone forever not exixting anymore

Comment: @bogdan yes thankyou thats what I mean

Comment: Ok, but you need to describe that better - it is not very clear from the text of your question.

Comment: yes sir :) english is my second language i will try

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a file , you can use

```
     My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("file\path")
```

If you want to delete an item in the list itself

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListView1.FocusedItem.Index < 0 Then
    Else
        ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(ListView1.FocusedItem.Index)
    End If
End Sub
```

please give us more details...

Comment: this removes the item from "View" but it dosnt delete the item from the disk/ storage device

Comment: have a look into...   My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("file\path")

Comment: @ Chris thats simple in theory but I can only get my listview to delete a refrence called 0 The exeact error states Additional information : InvalidArgument = Value of 0 is not valid for index .

Comment: @ABANDONDACOUNT you need to get the path to the file from the listview item, You haven't told us where the path is in the ListView, but it looks like you are trying to use the item's index rather than text that you are reading from the item.